# How to resolve inconsistent database table columns in local vs production (heroku)?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, git, heroku

For my rails application, I have a "Posts" table that has the columns: id, description, user_id, created_at, updated_at.

Locally, I ran the following query:

```
ALTER TABLE posts RENAME TO posts_old;
```

Then in my rails console, I ran:

```
require Rails.root + 'db/migrate/20130425060156_create_posts.rb'
CreatePosts.new.change
```

Then I ran the query:

```
INSERT INTO posts (id, user_id, content, created_at, updated_at)
SELECT id, user_id, content, created_at, updated_at FROM posts_old;
```

The query ran fine, but the problem I realized is that I was missing a "user_id" column in my new "Posts" table.

So I ran a migration and created a "user_id" column for the new "Posts" table.

I pushed up these changes up to git.

Lastly, I pushed these changes up to heroku. Due to the last migration: I ran

`heroku run rake db:migrate`

This is when I got an error. See below. My question is, how do I add a column to my new "Posts" table without conflicting with what is existing in my database on heroku?

```
Migrating to AddUserIdToPost (20131008050154)
==  AddUserIdToPost: migrating ================================================
-- add_column(:posts, :user_id, :integer)
rake aborted!
An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:

PG::DuplicateColumn: ERROR:  column "user_id" of relation "posts" already exists
: ALTER TABLE "posts" ADD COLUMN "user_id" integer/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:650:in `exec'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:650:in `block in execute'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:280:in `block in log'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:275:in `log'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:649:in `execute'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:1022:in `add_column'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/migration.rb:466:in `block in method_missing'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/migration.rb:438:in     `block in say_with_time'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/migration.rb:438:in `say_with_time'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/migration.rb:458:in `method_missing'
/app/db/migrate/20131008050154_add_user_id_to_post.rb:3:in `change'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/migration.rb:407:in `block (2 levels) in migrate'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/migration.rb:407:in `block in migrate'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:129:in `with_connection'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/migration.rb:389:in `migrate'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/migration.rb:528:in `migrate'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/migration.rb:720:in `block (2 levels) in migrate'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/migration.rb:775:in `call'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/migration.rb:775:in `block in ddl_transaction'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:192:in `transaction'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:208:in `transaction'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/migration.rb:775:in `ddl_transaction'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/migration.rb:719:in `block in migrate'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/migration.rb:700:in `each'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/migration.rb:700:in `migrate'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/migration.rb:570:in `up'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/migration.rb:551:in `migrate'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:193:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

Comment: Well to keep things managed always avoid issuing direct `ALTER` or `INSERT` statements in mysql console.Generate a migration for every schema changes or inserts.This will pay off later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updated AddUserIdToPost migration from

```
def change
    add_column :posts, :user_id, :integer
end
```

to this:

```
def up
    add_column :posts, :user_id, :integer
end

def down
end
```

Then ran the following:

> bundle exec rake db:rollback STEP=1
>
> bundle exec rake db:migrate

Then push up to git, heroku, and run heroku migration.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that the migration AddUserIdToPost is performed after the migration CreatePosts. And migration CreatePosts includes the column user_id. Remove "user_id" from migration CreatePosts. The attribute "user_id" will be created in migration AddUserIdToPost.

Comment: How do I remove the "user_id" from migration CreatePosts?